# selenium saving complete Webpage after applying with driver.find_element(by=By.LINK_TEXT, value=)

Tags: html, selenium-webdriver, save, local

Is there a way to saving complete webpage, (i.e. simulate the right click save as) in selenium? I want the complete HTML file saved in a specific folder.

selenium saving complete  webpage after  applying with `driver.find_element(by=By.LINK_TEXT, value=)`

I tried this, but it does not work.

`html = driver.page_source scraper = pd.read_html(html)`

Comment: there are probably a lot of different tools/extensions that do this.  A loooong time ago I used to run one that would do it and follow all external links and grab those sites too.  We'd run it all day long and end up with a ton of sites to test our read/write engine.  Web sites were a bit more simple back then, but I'd expect there's some good tools that would deal with most sites.  Doing a quick google search I found an extension for Chrome which did this a page at a time, so I'm sure you'll find what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save all the page content (HTML, images, css files, etc) you can simulate CTRL+S with

```
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl','s') # if you don't have it run pip install pyautogui
```

Alternatively, if you only want the HTML, then you can save the `driver.page_source` (which is a string) to a file.

```
with open("Output.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as text_file:
    text_file.write(driver.page_source)
```

Comment: @sethuge You are welcome! Were you able to save complete webpage?